# How to return index of specific pairs of values?

Tags: python, arrays

I need to find the index (row number) of specific pairs of value from an array. Below is example array.

```
A=[[357 131]
   [319 171]
   [229 196]
   [398 135]
   [242 148]
  ]
```

I want to know the index of [229 196] and [242 148] as their row number

```
  3  and 5
```

I was trying to use

```
A.index ([229 196]) or A.index([229 196])
```

but did not work. How to get the row number of specific pairs of values?

Comment: Why did you try that? Are you just guessing at syntax? Have you seen the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)?

Comment: I noted that array.index is for single value, not for pairs, but i could not find any syntax for index of pairs. So, I just tried that. Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [documentation regarding arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html). `A` should be defined this way :

```
>>> A=[[357,131],[319,171],[229,196],[398,135],[242,148]]
```

Your guess was right though, regarding how to access the index of the elements of the array :

```
>>> A.index([229,196])
2
>>> A.index([242,148])
4
```

Be careful, those return 2 and 4, and not 3 and 5 ! Indeed, the index of an array starts at 0, and not 1 ! You can check this by doing `A[0]`.

Hope it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong.
You may want to change from

```
A.index ([229 196])
```

to

```
A.index([229, 196])
```

Comment: and plus one if you want the index count from 1

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your components are lists of `ints`?  `[229 196]` should raise a syntax error.

If you are, indeed, using lists of ints, the following should work:

```
A.index([229, 196])
A.index([242, 148])
```

Otherwise try:

```
A.index(["229 196"])
```

If you are unsure what the type is, try:

```
type(A[0])  # first item in list
type(A[0][0])  # first item within first item of list
```